# cant upload file using phpexcel issue with file path

Tags: php, phpexcel

i am currently using phpexcel library to read my excel file which is to be uploaded by user . but i cannot at this moment :(

i am using this code, i cannot get the file path right at this moment and if some one could tell me , how to over ride existing file and renaming the input file.

file is being transferred to folder , but i cant get the path name correct in this line   $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('upload/'.$test);can any one help me ?

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$test= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
require_once('classes/phpexcel.php');
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('upload/'.$test);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex('0') ;
```

kindly help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use another solution like this for example:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

Comment: Probably you mean the temp-name instead of the file-name?

Comment: just wanted to say name, because 'load' wants a mandatory path. With tmp_name does not work!