# PHPExcel upload xls

Tags: phpexcel

Example

`   $name= $file;
    // upload file
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($name);

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
//$numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();


for ($i = 14; $i <= 39; $i++) {

    $rpu = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i)->getValue();
    $kwh = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('K'.$i)->getValue();



    $sql = "INSERT INTO cs(rpu, kwh) VALUES('$rpu','$kwh')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

the problem is that I can only upload files in the same folder where I have the php the issue is to upload a file anywhere except in the php root

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the uploaded file to the desired path with e.g. [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), and then specify the path to the phpExcel `load`-function.

See for instance this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972571/cant-upload-file-using-phpexcel-issue-with-file-path).